# Return user name by user id SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have got 3 tables :

users

```
id
username
```

images

```
id
user_id
image
```

user_follow

```
id
user_id
follow_id
```

I try to make query that will show all my friends and friends of my friends.
I need to get their usernames by their id (from table "users")

my query is :

```
$sql = "SELECT f.user_id, username, i.image, i.date FROM users u
      INNER JOIN user_follow f on (u.id = f.follow_id)
      LEFT OUTER JOIN images i on (f.follow_id = i.user_id)
      WHERE
      f.user_id = 3 OR f.user_id IN
      (
      select f2.follow_id
      from user_follow f2
      where f2.user_id = 3
      )
    ";
```

and itget this :

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 6
        [username] => 7777
        [image] => 
        [date] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 6
        [username] => 8888
        [image] => 86o99fyyocscfvbzlco0_380.jpg
        [date] => 2012-01-23 15:03:26
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 3
        [username] => 6666
        [image] => my.jpg
        [date] => 2012-01-23 16:40:28
    )
```

[user_id] => 6 = name in "users" table is 6666
[user_id] => 7 = name in "users" table is 7777

This query show everything good except user_id name. I need to do changes in query that it also will show user_id (from "user_follow" table) -> username (which is in "users table")

Answer (score 1):

add another `join` with `users` using `user_id` and show `username` from matching row?

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT f.user_id, fn.username, i.image, i.date
FROM
  users u
  INNER JOIN user_follow f on (u.id = f.follow_id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN images i on (f.follow_id = i.user_id)
  JOIN users AS fn ON (f.user_id=fn.id)
WHERE
  f.user_id = 3 OR f.user_id IN
  (
  select f2.follow_id
  from user_follow f2
  where f2.user_id = 3
  )
```

Comment: I am sorry for request can you write a full line of join, because when I try I get error or query do not start work correctly, do not show my friends and friends of my friends

Comment: still result is the same as I show above, [user_id] => 6 show as Id not username. fn.username show as [username] => 7777 and it was in my first query and it is ok. My goal is to do [username1] => 6666 (from [user_id] => 6) and [username2] => 7777 (from [follow_id] => 7)

Comment: I've changed the `ON` condition for join, maybe now I got what you want to have?

Comment: Now it change [username] => 7777 to [username] => 6666. In other words ['username'] get f.user_id but this line need to have f.follow_id

Comment: Do you mean like putting `u.id AS uuserid, u.username AS uusername`? I'm not sure I quite understand your intention. Are you talking about giving different names to select list or what?

Comment: giving different names will be cool ! The first what I need that sql will return user_id, follow_id (from "user_follow" table not id but usernames, which (usernames) are in "users" table and date, image from image table if user have it (now with this last two row everything is ok)

Comment: So, u.id, u.username will give you id and name of the user corresponding to follow_id and fn.id,fn.username will give you id and name of the user corresponding to user_id (from the user_follow table) what else do you want?